# Element's left edge is dynamic (inline...), but right edge is fixed?

Tags: html, css

Here is a demonstration: http://jsbin.com/egezog/edit#html,live

Sorry if this is newby, but I can't figure this out. I have a title, and I need (in decoration purposes) a line going from its edge to the right of the page (not an actual page, but a wrapper, but I have overflow hidden anyway). The wrapper is fixed in width, but the titles vary in length. I can't use absolute position, and I prefer not to use tables. And if we get this sorted out...

Here: http://jsbin.com/ibeciv/edit#html,live. So in the end, I actually prefer this all right aligned. You may ask, why do I need advice if it's there, implemented? Well, as you may see, the title is in two rows, which is unacceptable in my situation, and also, I prefer not to use tables.

I guess I can use float:right, to right align, but well, it depends on the implementation that I hope you'll advise to me. Thanks!

PS: jsfiddle is down for me right now, so here I used jsbin.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/osovev/2

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't know about white-space, thanks. Is there a way without tables though? This does work for me too, and you may submit it as an answer so that we could close this case, but since we are here, let's wait - maybe there's a simpler way. Thanks again though.

Comment: Be aware the solutions in the answers below that don't use tables will only work if the element that contains the title has a predictable background. Here's an example of how it can break: http://jsbin.com/ujawej/6/edit#html,live

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do it without tables and with support for an unknown background. Are you interested? Do you need to support old browsers like IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ujiquq/edit#html,live

Will work in IE8 and all modern browsers. The background of the parent element can be anything. The line will still be vertically centered no matter what `font-size` is chosen.

**HTML:**

```
<h3><span>The title</span></h3>
```

**CSS:**

```css
h3:after {
    content: '\00200B';
    background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAgABAIAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAACAAEAAAICBAoAOw==) left center repeat-x;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h3 > span {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty. Is there a way to make the line with code, not image? Just curious.

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could do what sandeep has done, and use a `border` combined with manually guessing the correct `margin-top` to apply. The only possible problem there is that amount of margin required varies with the font size. My answer will automatically work for any font size.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="title"><span>Title Here</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title {text-align:right;border-bottom:1px solid red;}
  span{background:#fff;float:right;margin-top:-9px;}
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/ibeciv/3/edit

**UPDATED**

Check this http://jsbin.com/ibeciv/4/edit

Comment: That's nice, and I've thought about it. My problem is that my background is a repeating pattern, and it would be noticable that there's a block around the title. Thanks for help anyway! There's another comment that solves it already, if you areinterested, then you may take a look too ;)

Comment: @sandeep Sandeep The Great CSS Man! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using tables:

http://jsbin.com/ujawej/5/edit

And here is the one with tables (from my comment):

http://jsbin.com/osovev/2

Comment: Danm, I am stupid -  I looked at the wrong link you attached. Nope, the background solution win't work, well, because I have an actual background on my site, not white colour (I should've mentioned that). That way, it would stand out, and I want it blending in... The table solution works though. I'll wait a bit, and if there's no other replies, will mark this as the solution again. Well, after all, it *is* a solution, although I dislike tables ;)